# Magento 2.4 category page product not load

Tags: product, category, magento2.4.2

Magento 2.4 category page default product collection doesn't load. And elasticsearch working perfect. So Please help me.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 3):

I have solve this issue below debugging steps with final solution :-

1. First i have check what query are pass in collection

**`EX:-`**

```
<?php
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection(); 
echo $_productCollection->getSelect();
exit ("Hello Mohit Patel");
?>
```

And in Collection **`search_tmp_`** value and other **`search_result`** not found in query.

2. I have check indexer_state table and **`catalogsearch_fulltext`** column status found invalid. And re-index command i have faced below issue

**`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"index [magento2_product_1_v7] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"index [magento2_product_1_v7] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"},"status":429}`**

3. I have search this related issue and found apply the below solution

Final Solution :-

Then follow below steps:

**Step 1 :** Go to your root project in command line

**Step 2 :** Run below mentioned command

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'
```

**Step 3 :** After running above command successfully, run another below mentioned command

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

After running above codes, run below mentioned commands

```
– php bin/magento setup:upgrade
– php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
– php bin/magento indexer:reindex
– php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**`THANKS.`**