# Magento 2.4.2 not showing products in category pages after version update

Tags: magento2, product, category, products, search

I have updated my Magento from 2.3.0 to 2.4.2, and seems to work fine, but one thing, if I go in any category page, I see no products, and even if I search for, I see no results. On the homepage there is the latests products grid, and I can see those. When I update the magento version, I have disabled elastic search and installed this one through those commands:

```
/usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}

/usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli /home/u129-kntmbqtlx5of/composer.phar require swissup/module-search-mysql-legacy --prefer-source --ignore-platform-reqs

/usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli bin/magento module:enable Swissup_SearchMysqlLegacy Swissup_Core

/usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli bin/magento setup:upgrade

/usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli bin/magento setup:di:compile

/usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli bin/magento indexer:reindex

/usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli bin/magento cache:clean

/usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli bin/magento cache:flush
```

but still nothing, I don't see the products in categories, any suggestion?

Comment: can you share your error log

Comment: and same issue i have faced i have resolved this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/337419/85907

Comment: enable Elasticsearch module and check Elasticsearch status and do this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/322516/magento-2-x-elasticsearch-category-products-not-showing,  after run indexing and cache clean command

Comment: I have also checked var\log\exception.log, and this is what I get https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351804/magento-2-4-2-not-showing-products-in-category-pages-after-update-here-the-log

Comment: Big change it has something to do with Elastic Search as suggested.

Comment: Is your theme compatible with Magento 2.4.2? Try switching to the default Magento theme and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.4.x switches to using Elasticsearch as management of category pages.

Try reindexing all the indexes.

```
bin/magento indexer:reset
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Make sure your Elasticsearch is connected before you do this.

Also check if you had any overrides for Catalog page filters. Many people used MySQL sorting to sort the pages - this no longer works and overrides that did that need to be removed.

UPDATE:

Looks like OP is using swissapps plugin that goes back to MySQL search.

@alexcr have you tried going through the manual?

https://docs.swissuplabs.com/m2/extensions/search-mysql-legacy/

```
php bin/magento setup:install --disable-modules=Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch7,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch
```

install module, then run:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch7 Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
```

Then check if its running:

```
bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine
```

If you need to change the engine:

```
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'lmysql'
```

Comment: no luck ! i can't solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching and reinstalling a vanilla version of 2.4.5 here is the fix.

Go to stores->configuration->catalog->catalog-> Allow All Products per Page
Set this to NO

bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush

Done.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check your elastic search connectivity on 9200 port using this command from ssh

```
curl localhost:9200
```

it causes due to elastic search unavailability, if above command giving connectivity error so install elastic search on your server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to 2.4.2 and found this solution corrected the issues in the database.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322623/58072

Here is the code I used.

```
SELECT *
FROM catalog_eav_attribute cea 
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
  AND backend_type IN ('text', 'varchar')
WHERE 
  cea.is_filterable = 1 OR cea.is_filterable_in_search = 1;
```

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute cea 
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
  AND backend_type in ('text', 'varchar')
SET 
  cea.is_filterable = 0, cea.is_filterable_in_search = 0
WHERE 
  cea.is_filterable = 1 OR cea.is_filterable_in_search = 1;
```

Then clear caches and reindex. Try load a different category page to avoid browser cache issues.